# Is my routine okay?

Tags: workout-routines, bodyweight-exercises, calisthenics

Fist of all:

- Height: 175 cm  (5´9´´)
- Weight: 65.3 kg (143 lbs)
- Age:    15 years

Well my workout is split in three days:

Tuesday  //  TRICEPS and BACK

```
Pull-ups:                        8 reps
Bent-Over One Arm Dumbbell Rows: 8 reps
```

(No rest between exercises) Rest 1 minute and repeat 2 previous exercises

```
Narrow Grip Seated Cable Rows:   8 reps
Dumbbell Pullovers:              8 reps
```

(No rest between exercises) Rest 1 minute and repeat 2 previous exercises

```
Close grip Dumbbells press:      8 reps
Bench Dips:                      8 reps
```

(No rest between exercises) Rest 1 minute and repeat 2 previous exercises

```
Diamond push-ups:                8 reps
Triceps Machine:                 8 reps
```

(No rest between exercises) Rest 1 minute and repeat 2 previous exercises

Thursday //  LEGS and SHOULDERS

```
Similar
```

Saturday //  BICEPS and  CHEST

```
Similar
```

( At the end of every workout, I perform ABDS/CORE exercises )

Additional:

```
First week:    3 sets /  10 reps
Second week:   4 sets /  10 reps
Third week:    3 sets /  12 reps
Fourth week:   4 sets /  12 reps
```

Then:

- I go and back to gym in bike in 30 minutes total
- 1 hour of work out and then 30 min of ABDS / CORE exercises
- Properly warm-up before start

I wanna focus on build muscle, so tell me if Im in the right way.

PS: I´m gonna move to CALISHTENICS training, I´ll build a pull-up and parallel bars in my house next month so, Do u think this model will be the best for it? if not, please suggest me one, thanks for all

Comment: How can your leg-day be similar to your chest-day? Why are you supersetting? Why are you using a 3-day-split when you only train three times a week? Who gave you that plan and _what the hell_ made that person think this would be a good beginner's routine? Erm, to answer the question, it's pretty bad.

Answer (score 3):

First point I see is that you should set your expectations well.  At 15, your body is just beginning to be at a place where you can see muscular development.  Everybody is a little different, so it may be a year or two before you see any appreciable muscle mass being built.  However, keep at it.

In all honesty, what you have outlined is too much variation for a beginner workout.  Things you'll want to make sure you have in your beginner routine:

- 3-6 different exercises max.  Having more doesn't build more muscle
- Get your nutrition in line.  You will have to eat more food to build muscle, but you don't want to gain weight too fast or it's just fat.  Eat good food, and try to gain no more than 3/4 lb a week.  If you don't like the way you look (too pudgy), then focus on loosing a couple pounds.
- Make sure you are in bed for 8 hours straight per night.  You build muscle while you sleep, and it's the most anabolic thing you can do.
- Minimize partying.  I'm not saying avoid all parties, but they do keep you up late and you end up eating and drinking things that don't help you build muscle.
- Periodize.  That just means you'll cycle between trying to add muscle and trying to get stronger.  In the very beginning you'll probably add both easily.
- Use compound lifts to do the major work, and isolation exercises to dial it in.

Since your focus is on muscle, I would have an A and B workout that you focus on and just trade them off the 3 days a week you train.  Basically, on week 1 you would go ABA and on week 2 you would go BAB.  What I'm about to outline is just a general beginner routine:

**Workout A:** full body, chest and arm emphasis

- Squats: 3x8 (try to get hips below parallel)
- Bench Press: 3x8 (use a spotter but don't let them touch the bar except for handoffs or if you truly do get stuck)
- Pull-Ups: 3x8 (work up to 3x8 BW pull ups if you can)
- Curls: 3x8 (pick one variation for the day and do it)
- DB Flies: 3x8 (flat, incline or decline, but one variation for the day)

**Workout B:** full body, shoulders and leg emphasis

- Leg Press: 3x8
- Overhead Press: 3x8 (pick one variation)
- Romanian Deadlift: 3x8
- Dumbbell Row: 3x8 (alternate days between elbows tucked and elbows out, be strict)
- DB Front Raise: 3x8
- Free exercise slot: 3x8 (whatever you feel like needs more attention, isolation exercise of your choice)

For the first 3 exercises in each day, keep adding weight week to week until you can't get all 3 sets of 8.  When that happens you'll be changing the rep scheme like this:

- 3x8 to 5x5 (remember the weight you made the switch here)
- 5x5 to 8x3
- 8x3 to 5x8 (use the weight from the first bullet point)
- 5x8 to 7x5
- 7x5 to 12x3 (after this you are no longer a beginner and you need more advanced templates)

For the last 2-3 exercises (your isolation work), start with 3x8 and just try to add one more rep each time you do them until you hit 3x12.  Then add weight and start over with 3x8.  The change in rep schemes is all you need to do for periodization.  When the sets get shorter you are focusing more on strength and less on size, however the volume is there to maintain the size you've already acquired.  When you drop back down in weight, you add more volume which will help build more size.  Just as you can't ignore size when you are building strength, you can't ignore strength when you are building size.  Sets of 8 primarily build size, sets of 5 are balanced between size and strength, and sets of 3 are primarily for strength.

As far as what weight to start with, I would much rather start too light and build momentum than start too heavy and feel overwhelmed by it all.  I personally started with just the bar on all the major exercises.  When you increase weight by just 5 lbs every time you get in the gym it doesn't take long for the weight to start feeling heavy.